# Application of Cayley’s theorem in Sylow’s theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, cayley-graphs

I’ve just started reading Sylow’s theorems. I have heard that Cayley’s theorems are applied in Sylow’s theorem. Can someone exactly point out where in the three Sylow’s theorem is Cayley’s theorem explicitly  used?

Comment: Do you mean Cauchy instead of Cayley?

Comment: @TokenToucan no, I meant Cayley only.

Comment: A standard application (so only worth a comment IMO) is that if the order of a group is $n\equiv2\pmod4$ then the group has an index two subgroup. Namely the subgroup of elements corresponding to an *even* permutation in the Cayley mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one of the several possible proofs of Sylow I uses Cayley's theorem and it's not a very common one (at least not in my experience; I never ran into it as a student). According to [Waterhouse](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00327877) it's essentially due to Frobenius (I had access to this pdf and then lost it so unfortunately I am going off of memory and might be misremembering). It starts with the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ such that $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then $H$ also has a Sylow $p$-subgroup, which is given by its intersection with some conjugate of $P$.

(Here a Sylow $p$-subgroup is a $p$-subgroup whose index is coprime to $p$. This is not equivalent to "maximal $p$-subgroup" until you prove Sylow I + II.)

*Proof.* Consider the action of $H$ on the cosets $G/P$. By hypothesis, $|G/P|$ isn't divisible by $p$, hence at least one orbit of this action also has size not divisible by $p$. This orbit contains some coset $gP$, and its size is $\frac{|H|}{|\text{Stab}(gP)|}$ where the stabilizer of $gP$ consists of all $h \in H$ such that

$$hgP = gP \Leftrightarrow g^{-1} hgP = P \Leftrightarrow g^{-1} hg \in P$$

and hence $\text{Stab}(gP) = (g^{-1} H g) \cap P$. So the stabilizer is a subgroup of $P$ and hence also a $p$-group, and also its index in $H$ is coprime to $p$, so we conclude that it's a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $g^{-1} Hg$. Conjugating, we get that $H \cap (gPg^{-1})$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. $\Box$

Now by Cayley's theorem, every finite group $H$ embeds into some symmetric group $S_n$. So you can prove Sylow I by proving that the symmetric groups have Sylow $p$-subgroups, and these can be constructed explicitly (although they're somewhat annoying to describe; if you want to try doing this you can reduce to the case that $n$ is a power of $p$ where it's easier). You can also embed $S_n$ into $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and exhibit a Sylow $p$-subgroup there, which is just the upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal.

This argument, slightly simplified, gives an independent proof of Cauchy's theorem, which is essentially Cauchy's original proof of Cauchy's theorem; it ran $9$ pages. Note also that setting $H$ to be a $p$-group in the lemma immediately gives Sylow II, in the strong form that not only are all Sylow $p$-subgroups conjugate but every $p$-subgroup is a subgroup of a Sylow $p$-subgroup, so "Sylow" and "maximal" coincide.

Comment: This is really neat. I had never seen that argument before.

Comment: @Tobias: honestly I found it kind of shocking when I came across it. It makes the proof of Sylow I very short and I remember it being long and confusing as an undergraduate. The proof I saw as an undergraduate was the proof due to Wielandt on Wikipedia, involving subsets of size $p^k$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Proof_of_the_Sylow_theorems

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you tell me how to simplify these arguments to get to Cauchy's independent proof? This is just an amazing piece of work!

Comment: @Additi: I just finished a blog post with the details: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2020/11/01/meditation-on-the-sylow-theorems-i/

Comment: Thanks a lot @QiaochuYuan